# Scrollbar-button increment/decrement

Tags: css

In css, how can I set scrollbar-button to scroll up and down by page instead of line by    line? I want scrollbar-button to scroll up/down by page so i can get to the bottom/top of the page quicker.

Comment: Users expect scrollbar and its buttons to behave in a particular way.  If the user really wants to get to the top or bottom of the page quickly, they can use the home or end keys respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can not alter the browser scrollbar like that. You can add your own buttons on the page that can do that with the help of JavaScript. Or the user can use the page up/down buttons on their keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom scrollbar replacement library like http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/